# Getting vinculum in fractions with Asana Math and unicode-math

Tags: math-mode, xetex

With this minimal example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
\begin{document}
$\frac{2\pi r}{r} = 2\pi$
\end{document}
```

I am unable to get the horizontal bar or vinculum for the fraction on the left.

I am new to unicode-math, and want to use the Asana Math font with Minion Pro as my main font, compiling the document with xelatex.

Can someone please suggest what is wrong and how to correct it?

Many thanks.

Comment: Which versions of unicode-math and XeTeX are you using?

Comment: XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.2-0.9997.4 (TeX Live 2010)

Comment: unicode-math.sty    2010/09/27 v0.5b Unicode maths in XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are possibly using a 64bit operating system and the 64bit version of XeTeX. There seems to be a long-standing bug in 64bit XeTeX that makes it basically unusable with unicode-math. 32bit XeLaTeX compiles your example correctly.

If you want to continue using XeLaTeX, you should install the 32bit binaries from TeX Live and change $PATH accordingly. (On modern systems using 32bit binaries in a 64bit OS shouldn't be a problem.)

Comment: This is a known bug that should be fixed in the CVS version of xetex soon.  The bug has been identified and a solution found.

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem and here is my output with current TeXLive2010 and the otf version of Asana from CTAN. I run the document with lualatex.
[image]

Comment: Thanks Herbert. I have the same, correct, results with lualatex but not with xelatex. I can use lualatex for now as a workaround, but need to find out why it does not work with xelatex.

Comment: give a single line space before and after image inclusion to make the image get displayed-mode.